# Is moonlight a significant condition for making life possible on earth?

Tags: earth-rotation, moon, light

We know of course that light from the sun is a fundamental component to making life possible on earth because of the energy it provides. Does the light that is reflected off of the moon make a significant impact on the earth as well?

For example - at night, would it be at lot colder on earth without moonlight? And would it basically be pitch-dark on earth without moonlight? Or do stars and other astronomical entities provide a significant amount of light compared to the moon?

Answer (score 2):

One significant biological event that requires a specific "type" of moonlight is the reproduction of corals in [Great Barrier Reef](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Barrier_Reef), in Australia.

'[One week each year in spring, after a full moon](https://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2007/10/071019-coral-spawning.html), millions of corals release eggs and sperm in what Bill Leggat, a co-author of the new study, called "a slow symphony."'

'[An ancient light-sensitive gene](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2007/10/071019093814.htm) has been isolated that appears to act as a trigger for the annual mass spawning of corals across a third of a million square kilometres of Australia’s Great Barrier Reef, shortly after a full moon.'

Comment: This is interesting, although I'm really wondering about very large effects. Do you have any information about the difference in energy or visibility on the earth that the moon provides?